# How to understand the sentence in the C++ primer 3rd

Tags: c++, abstract-class, information-hiding, inline-functions

Following is an extract taken from chapter 7.6 of the `<C++ primer (3rd)>` by Stanley B. Lippman Josée Lajoie.

> A function specified as inline is expanded "in line" at each point in the program in which it is invoked. For example,
>
> int minVal2 = min( i, j );
>
> is expanded during compilation into
>
> int minVal2 = i < j ? i : j;
>
> The run-time overhead of making min() a function is thus removed.
>   min() is declared inline by specifying the inline keyword before the function's return type in the function declaration or definition:
>
> inline int min( int v1, int v2 ) { /* ... */ }
>
> Note, however, that the inline specification is only a recommendation to the compiler. The compiler may choose to ignore this
>   recommendation, because the function declared inline is not a good candidate for expansion at the point of call. A recursive function,
>   such as rgcd(), for example, cannot be completely expanded at the point of call (although its first invocation can). A 1,200-line
>   function is also likely not to be expanded at the point of call. In general, the inline mechanism is meant to optimize small, straight-
>   line, frequently called functions. **It is of primary importance in the support of information hiding in the design of abstract data types,**
>   such as the IntArray class introduced in Section 2.3 with its size() inline member function.

Can someone please explain the sentence marked as bold ?

Comment: Provide some more context please.

Comment: The sentence is referring to whatever came before it.

Comment: If you don't understand it, how can you assume that your version has the same meaning??

Comment: Well, inline member functions go against the whole idea of information hiding so "it" isn't inline functions.

Comment: I want to say ,I don't understand the meaning of the sentence in programming , not the sentence itself.

Comment: "it" is the inline functions .Thanks.

Comment: Either post the entire sentense with context, or give up your hope to get any help here

Comment: I assume you mean Lippmann/Lajoie/Moo? I have the 4th edition, and can't find anything resembling that sentence...???

Comment: I disagree with the sentence, but I think its meaning is clear. What part of it do you not understand? "Primary importance"? "Abstract data types"? "Information hiding"?

Comment: how does the inline function support the information hiding in the design of abstract data types?

Comment: Probably what they mean is that the design of the standard containers means that a lot of operations go through levels of indirection (e.g. `std::vector::iterator::operator++`, which is a function call but all it *needs* to do is increment a pointer), and that without inlining this would be unacceptably slow. It's certainly true that inlining sometimes makes a crucial performance difference, I'd question whether the best way to express that is to say that it's "of primary importance to information hiding". It's of primary importance to the fact that the design results in optimizable code.

Comment: Yeah, the "Primary importance"!!!

Comment: @JerikcXIONG I have added the complete paragraph and modified the tags, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the full text of the 3rd edition here, but from the context you've posted, it's clear what he's saying.

Imagine a kind of 'vector' class.

```
class Vector {
private: 
  int * data; // pointer to data
```

There are several ways it could provide access to the vector size:

Choice 1: a public member variable:

```
public:
  int datasize;
```

Choice 2: a private variable with a public accessor

```
private:
  int datasize; 

public:
  int getSize(); // body can be hidden in CPP, but would be { return datasize;};
```

Choice 3: as 2, but with an inline accessor

```
private:
  int datasize; 

public:
  inline int getSize() { return datasize; };
```

Now, #1 has poor data hiding, but great performance. #2 has great data hiding, but poor performance. #3 has good data hiding, and possibly great performance. (remember inline is just a hint)

In my view the data hiding of #3 is slightly inferior to #2 because the function code is revealed in the header - even if you can't access the member. So, I'd rewrite his statement along the lines of...

> Inline Functions provide a good compromise between the requirements of
>   Data Hiding versus Performance.

I wouldn't agree that it's of "primary importance", as it's just a hint to the compiler.

Comment: Good answer.  A couple of comments: I think that Lipman's point is about the importance of using functions (accessors/mutators).  That they are inline is less important.  Also, I don't think #3 is worse than #2.  It doesn't really matter if the "hidden" information is really invisible.  It matters more that it is inaccessible and that you can change it without any side-effects.  Of course that's just my opinion.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

- "In the abstract data type design, it has played a major role in
  supporting of information hiding"

**Data Type:** You are probably familiar with this term.  It can be an integer, a string, etc. or some more complex type like a B-Tree, a complex number, etc.

**Abstract Data Type:** These are data types that represent some real-life object.

e.g.

```
struct SCustomer
{
   string name;
   string address;
   int    id;
   enum CreditRanking { Good, Poor, Bankrupt };
   CreditRating rating;
};
```

*CreditRating* is an abstract data type, as is *SCustomer*.

**Information Hiding:** By encapsulating information inside the abstract data type, a designer can think about operations performed on/with a customer without the actual implementation of the SCustomer cluttering up their thought process.

The information is not really hidden, they can look inside the definition of the data type if they want to, but in many cases it is easier to just concentrate on the high (abstract) level and not think about the small details.

You can think of it like this:

- Think about low-level details and build a set of objects.
- Ignore the low-level details and combine the objects into bigger objects or into an application.

The above is over-simplified a bit, but I hope it gives you the flavour.

Does that help?

Comment: Not helpful at all, it doesn't answer what inline functions have to do with it. And btw, neither `SCustomer` nor `CreditRating` are abstract

Comment: Inline functions were not mentioned in the question when I started writing the answer.  I can only answer the question as it is asked.  I don't have E.S.P.

Comment: Reference to "7.6 Inline Functions" has been there right from the beginning

Comment: Thanks! Although you don't solve my problem , I have got so much according to your response.

Comment: @aleguna - OK, I mised the chapter title.  I was looking at the actual sentence.  Notwithstanding that, though my answer was not complete, I strongly dispute that it was not helpful.  I guess it is easier to mark down other people's reputation than to contribute something useful.

Comment: @aleguna - By the way, my examples are *abstract data types* in the computer science sense.  They are very simple, but they abstract a real-life concept.  Are you confusing this with the concept of abstract (pure virtual) classes in C++ and Java?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the late appearance of "inline functions".

Calling an inline function is as fast as putting the code "in line".  Some programmers might hesitate to encapsulate their logic in functions due to the overhead in speed and size, but using an inline function minimised any overhead to (usually) a trivial amount.

Think of this code:

```
int customer_code = get_code(customer_name);
int product_code  = get_id(product_name);
bool credit_ok    = check_credit(customer_code);
int order_number  = create_order(customer_code, credit_ok, 
                                 product_code, quantity);
print_order(order_number, customer_code, customer_name, 
            product_code, product_name, quantity);
```

An information hiding version might look like this.

```
order ord = cust.make_order(product, quantity);
order.print();
```

Of this forms part of a much bigger program you can make the high-level code a great deal easier to undrstand.  Somebody still needs to design the objects customer, order, product, etc. but they only need to concentrate on one thing at a time and then the bojects can be used throughout the program.

Comment: what's the late appearance of "Inline functions" refers to? Thanks.

Comment: Initially it was hard to understand what you were referring to, as you had not yet explained about inline functions, so I wrote some general comments on abstract data types and information hiding.  This deeply offended one of the commenters.  When your intention became more clear, I wrote this post about inline functions specifically.